# How to communicate data from ReactJS and Python?

Tags: python, json, reactjs

I'm building an app in which I need to communicate data from and to ReactJS and Python. It needs to go both ways - but I'm more concerned about the React part right now. At first I considered JSON, but couldn't find any resources/ libraries to update JSON files, and people said I should stay away from that. Other than literally creating a text file with data in it, what are my options? The application has to do with getting stock data from a python API, doing calculations on it, and sending the data to ReactJS to render on a webpage. I also need ReactJS to send account data back to Python where we do our MySQL. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can go with flask as backend and react as frontend. And use axios API library to interact with the flask server.

Answer (score 0):

Since the ReactJS app is a front-end application, your only real choice to ensure security is exposing an API on the python app which the ReactJS app talks to (via Websockets for example since you're mentioning a bidirectional communication). Maybe take a look at something like Flask with the flask-socketio package.